# Trouble with multiplatform (Windows, MacOSX, Linux) application using readline

Tags: linux, macos, bash, netbeans, multiplatform

I'm writing a multiplatform (Windows, Linux and MacOSX) app in C using Netbeans IDE.

It is shell based (bash) and i'm using readline and history for data input.

Additionaly, i want to overwrite shortcut keys (Ctrl + A, Ctrl + B, ...), so i used rl_bind_key function.

rl_bind_key works properly in Windows, but doesn't work in Linux and MacOSX, it always returns -1.

Another trouble i have is that inside Netbeans (shell integrated to IDE), everything runs OK, but outside Netbeans Shell my application looks incomplete. I think that these behavior is due to shell configutation, how can I export configuration from one shell to another..?

Answer (score 2):

**How to Fix it:**

`OS X` is using an ***ancient*** version of `readline`. To fix the issue, just upgrade to a newer version. Just run this in the terminal (*I am using Homebrew as my package manager*):

```
brew install readline
brew link readline --force
```

*The `force` is required as it supposed to override a system library.*

If the code above worked for you and you don't care why it failed stop reading here.

**What went wrong?**

For some reason, the function was not implemented to accept callbacks but rather just to enable or disable the `rl_insert` function. Even though it was documented to be able to bind an arbitrary callback.

Below is the exact implementation of the function in `readline 1.*` *(which is the version used in OS X)*:

```
int rl_bind_key(int c, rl_command_func_t *func)
{
    int retval = -1;

    if (h == NULL || e == NULL)
        rl_initialize();

    if (func == rl_insert) {
        /* XXX notice there is no range checking of ``c'' */
        e->el_map.key[c] = ED_INSERT;
        retval = 0;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

As you see, except for the cases when `func == rl_insert`, the function always returns `-1`.

Comment: _P.S. I did quite a lot of digging..._